# Find several maximum values in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, max

may you please help me to find out why this code shows only one last name, I need to show all who has maximum values
I do test and see that it finds the maximum, it compares, but shows only one last name

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        TreeMap<String, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> sArray = new ArrayList<>();

        while (reader.ready()) {
            String st = reader.readLine();
            sArray.add(st);
        }


        for (String s : sArray) {
            String[] array = s.split(" ");
            String name = array[0];
            double price = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
            if (map.containsKey(name)) {
                price = price + map.get(name);
            }
            map.put(name, price);
        }

        Double maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(map.values()));  // This will return max value in the Hashmap
        System.out.println(maxValueInMap);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue() + " | " + (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap));// Itrate through hashmap
            if (entry.getValue() == maxValueInMap) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());     // Print the key with max value
            }
        }

        reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the output your program produces?

Comment: here is :)   3.0
борзов - 2.5 | false
гномов - 3.0 | true
гномов
громов - 1.0 | false
колобков - 3.0 | false
миронов - 2.0 | false
петров - 2.0 | false
серов - 3.0 | false
сидоров - 2.0 | false
троцкий - 3.0 | false

Comment: sorry for last names in Rus, can't add it in more readable way, but as you may noticed it shows false for those who has the maximum to 3.0

Comment: Try to compare the `Double` instances with `equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare number objects with `.equals()` instead of `==`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue() + " | " + (entry.getValue().equals(maxValueInMap)));// Itrate through hashmap
            if (entry.getValue().equals(maxValueInMap)) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());     // Print the key with max value
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had this idea too, but haven't checked as I thought why I need to use equals with Double

Comment: Double is an object, that's why

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to return the names with highest price, you are better off mapping price to names (either by mapping price to a set of names or by using guava's multimap).

You can even do better by only keeping a set of names and a variable to keep track of the most expensive name.
When you encounter something more expensive than your current most expensive name, "reset" the set you'll return.

Comment: thank you, Roy, I tried to add the names to a separate ArrayList, but the problem was with == as I see now

Comment: Yes, my answer was a suggestion to improve the time complexity of your solution. Of course the problem you encountered was due to using == instead of equals :)